R summarise with optional columns
I create a lot of columns via summarize and delete columns that I don't need in a second step. Another option would be to create each column separately and then join them using join, which is probably not faster.
The program code currently looks like this:
Data <- Data %>%
    group_by_at(group_by_Vektor) %>%
    summarize(var_1 = sum(var_1), 
              var_2 = sum(var_2), 
              ...
              var_n = sum(var_n),
             .groups = 'drop')
if (!condition_1) {
    Data <- select(Data, -var_1))
}
if (!condition_2) {
    Data <- select(Data, -var_2))
}
...
if (!condition_n) {
    Data <- select(Data, -var_2))
}

I am looking for something like this:
Data <- Data %>%
    group_by_at(group_by_Vektor) %>%
    summarize(if(condition_1, var_1 = sum(var_1)), 
              if(condition_2, var_2 = sum(var_2), 
              ...
              if(condition_n, var_n = sum(var_n)),
             .groups = 'drop')

Thank you very much!
Roland

I think you are looking for case_when.

How are the conditions created/stored? you can do across(var_1:var_n, sum)

Thank you, across makes the current code much shorter, but how can I combine across with conditions? For each column exists a boolean variable with TRUE or FALSE. This indicates whether the column should be calculated or not.

If you set up the variables and associated conditions in a list, you can use mapply and then merge the results with inner_join.
Suppose your data looks like this:
df <- data.frame(group_by_Vektor=rep(1:2, each=5), 
                 var_1=1:10, var_2=2:11, var_3=3:12)
df
   group_by_Vektor var_1 var_2 var_3
1                1     1     2     3
2                1     2     3     4
3                1     3     4     5
4                1     4     5     6
5                1     5     6     7
6                2     6     7     8
7                2     7     8     9
8                2     8     9    10
9                2     9    10    11
10               2    10    11    12


set up the variables and conditions:
vars <- list('var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3')
Conditions <- list(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)

Create a custom function to summarise depending on the condition:
f <- function(var, value) {
  if(value) df |> 
    group_by(group_by_Vektor) |> 
    summarise_at(vars(var), sum)
}

Then call this function using the vars and conditions and then merge them together.
sum_df <- mapply(function(x, y) f(x, y), vars, Conditions)
Reduce(inner_join, Filter(Negate(is.null), sum_df))


# A tibble: 2 × 3
  group_by_Vektor var_1 var_3
            <int> <int> <int>
1               1    15    25
2               2    40    50


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

